# java by default Constructor

Tags: java, default-constructor

```
public class ConStru
{
    public ConStru(int bc)
    {

    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            ConStru conStru = new ConStru();

    }

}
```

it is not working. giving the error.

Comment: Since you have provided a constructor, no default constructor will be inserted by the JVM.

Comment: What error you got? Which line? Please elaborate your question (edit your question)

Comment: Well, your constructor takes one argument and you try to construct with 0 arguments - what's confusing you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an integer to the constructor as

```
ConStru conStru = new ConStru(1);
```

Also remove public from "ConStru" class,

Comment: Why would `public` need to be removed?

Comment: because there can only be one public class per .java file.

Comment: You are making an assumption that the OP has both classes in the same file. This is one of the reasons why you should refrain from answering unclear questions that don't even mention the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add another constructor:

```
public ConStru()
{

}
```

Or create object with an int parameter:

```
ConStru conStru = new ConStru(1234);
```